# Adding unique pointer of objects to map

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, stl, unique-ptr

I am trying to add unique pointer to map.

```
auto monkey= std::unique_ptr<Animal> (new Animal(1,"Tom"));

std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<const Animal>> animals;    //Map of animals

animals.insert(pair<int, unique_ptr<Animal>>(1,monkey));    // Error here


Error:error: no matching function for call to 'std::pair<int, std::unique_ptr<Animal> >::pair(int&, std::unique_ptr<Animal>&)'
```

what would be the way to add it ??

Comment: Try this `myMap.insert(std::make_pair(0, std::unique_ptr<Class1>(new Class1())));` on your example

Comment: `animals.insert(pair<int, unique_ptr<Animal>>(1,std::move(monkey)));` unique_ptr can be only moved, not copied.

Comment: Okay it seems to be working. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

`std::unique_ptr` is not copiable, but movable, you have to `std::move` it.

You might do:

```
animals.emplace(1, std::move(monkey));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you using the following when trying to insert `std::unique_ptr` into the `std::map`:

```cpp
animals.insert(std::make_pair(1, std::unique_ptr<Animal>(new Animal(1,"Tom"))));
```

or

```cpp
animals.insert(std::make_pair(1, std::make_unique<Animal>(1,"Tom")));
```

First, prefer using `std::make_pair` over `std::pair` constructor because with `std::pair` you need to specify the types of both elements, whereas `std::make_pair` will deduce the types of the elements that are passed to it.

Second, as the other answer says, `std::unique_ptr` can't be copied because it is unique. It can only be moved by `std::move`. In this case, since you are passing an r-value reference to the `std::make_pair` function it is being moved.